# EF6 - Include objects with List<Func<T, object>>

Tags: c#, linq, include, entity-framework-6, entity

I want to `Include` objects to query by "Funcs", not by strings. This time I do it that way (`pagedListFunc.Includes` is `List<string>`):

```
foreach (var include in pagedListFunc.Includes)
{
    query = query.Include(include);
}
```

I want to use this list:

```
IncludeFuncs = new List<Func<Dicts, object>>()
{
    x => x.AspNetUsers,
    x => x.DictDomains
};
```

When I try to use pagedListFunc.IncludeFuncs (in fact, it's above list: `List<Func<T, object>>`):

```
foreach (var include in pagedListFunc.IncludeFuncs)
{
    query = query.Include(x => include(x)); // doesn't work
    // or
    query = query.Include(include); // wrong parameter error
}
```

How to use `IncludeFuncs` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type for the parameter is `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, which means that your `IncludeFuncs` must be of type `List<Expression<Func<Dicts, object>>()` as stated in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx).

As a sidenote, instead of using a `List`, this would be a nice use case for the [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword and a simple array. With that approach, you could specify a variable number of arguments when calling the method.

This would look like this for example (pseudocode):

```
public Dicts GetById(int id, params Expression<Func<Dicts, object>>[] includeProps)
{
    ...
    foreach(var include in includeProps)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
GetById(1, x => x.AspNetUsers, x => x.DictDomains);
```

Comment: I tried yesterday with `Expression<Func<Dicts, object>>` but something didn't work. Today it is working (lol). Anyway you are correct, thanks!